# How does pointer data stored in MachO __objc_classlist section rebased when run a iOS app?

Tags: ios, mach-o

In MachOView, I can see that in a iOS binary file, class pointers are stored in section __objc_classlist. They are absolute address values which point to class Data in section __objc_data. But we known that iOS use ASLR, so when loaded, the real address must be different.

I checked the "getsectiondata" method, can not found any rebase logic.

So the question is:

1. when and how does the pointer Data rebased?
2. Is the rebased data dirty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dyld` handles rebasing as part of loading the binary, long before you call `getsectiondata`.  The `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` load command within the binary points to the rebase opcodes which contain information about which addresses to update and how.

You can use `xcrun dyldinfo -rebase <binary>` to see the list of addresses that `dyld` will rebase. You'll see entries for each class within `__DATA,__objc_classlist`. You can set `DYLD_PRINT_REBASINGS=1` in the environment prior to launch to have `dyld` print out each address it rebases.

And yes, since `dyld` modifies data as it rebases it, the page no longer matches the underlying storage and is dirty. Avoiding dirtying pages during load has been a motivation for switching some Objective-C data structures from using pointers to relative offsets.